# Synonym for advertisement, with root the same as information?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

What is the word which has the same root as information, and has the same or similar meaning as  advertisement? It is pronounced similarly to infantory. Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for a noun, right?

Comment: yes.....................

Comment: Do you mean **Infographic**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has commented that he may have misunderstood the phrase "ad inventory".

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of

> infomercial

which is a combination of "information" and "commercial".
It is usually an extended advertisement explaining the product at length.

Comment: thanks, but it is not informarcial. I heard someone said something sounding like informatory.

Comment: But not "informatory"? "Informatory" does mean to have information but is not specific to advertisements.

Comment: ok. I now think that what I heard is "inventory" as in "ad inventory". I thought it to be the synonym of advertisement, but now realize I might be wrong.